# issues with php getimagesize

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the height and width of an image of my wordpress site using php. I do not want to use the wordpress get attachment.

I have use the following code to no success

```
<?php  list($width, $height) = getimagesize('http://scholldesign.com/wp-     content/uploads/2015/06/antonioni-2.jpg');echo $width; ?>
```

Comment: External url problem possibly, do you have this error in your log? getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Comment: It works fine, just fix the URL of image, it has some spaces that should not be there.

Comment: In the actual code there are no spaces, when I copy pasted into stackoverflow it went over two lines and the spaces appeared.  

Definitely no problem with the url as on the next line i have 

<img src="http://scholldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/antonioni-2.jpg" alt=" " class="firstPic portraitpic oneimage">

and the picture is appearing

Comment: Then enable error reporting, there must be some kind of warning/error.

Comment: ok i tried the same code with my facebook picture which is a picture online so anyone can copy code and try it and it still doesnt work

<?php $size = getimagesize('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/10403253_10155975242170179_5700796885329640534_n.jpg?oh=e721f85b93035787c128c2c7228d22c5&oe=562A39CA&__gda__=1445409042_854b0a7898d60c0a205b67cd584a2efe'); print_r($size); ?>